# neo4j import script endless loop because 2 properties with same name

Tags: import, neo4j, cypher

I just managed to freeze my whole environment with a cypher import script. The process was running with 99% CPU uncontrollably until we killed it.

I am not sure, but I think the bug was in the import script - trying to set 2 properties with the same name - reading like

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///import.csv' AS import FIELDTERMINATOR ';'
... (some WITH / WHERE clauses)
CREATE (:Mylabel {myproperty: import.column1, myproperty: import.column2});
```

Does anyone have experience with behaviour like that?

**EDIT:**

I am not allowed to copypaste the exact code, but I can try and leave it semantically intact:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///db.csv' AS row FIELDTERMINATOR ';'
WITH row
WHERE row.typerow = 'Some_Identifier'
WITH head(collect(row.id)) as aid, row.exclusive AS excl, toInteger(row.alwsel) AS alwsel
CREATE (:Mylabel:Mytype {aid: toInteger(aid), exclusive: toString(excl), 
exclusive: CASE WHEN alwsel=1 THEN true ELSE NULL END});
```

As was inquired below: there is no constraint on the property in question. I am currently not able to do any tests. I will be in a few days.

Comment: Can you test that with just one line in your import.csv ? While there is an obvious issue in the Cypher syntax, if it does not finish (or throw an error) with one line that is indeed a bug ...

Comment: This works (and finishes) with one line :
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///person.csv' AS import
CREATE (:Person {name: import.name, name: import.description});
So it may not be that ... can you provide the full Cypher syntax ? Also, can you specify if there is a (unique) index on the "myproperty" ?

Comment: @Tom Geudens please see my edit above!

Comment: Also please share the query plan (with EXPLAIN) and your data volume and memory config

Comment: The first "WITH row" is unnecessary i.m.o. ... and what are you trying to accomplish with "WITH head(collect(row.id)) as aid ..." exactly ? That would put all id's (from all rows) in a list and then you'd take the first ?

Comment: do you think the `WITH row` is causing the problem or are you giving "cosmetic" advice there? the collect part is to accomplish only creating one `:Mylabel` object where the whole row apart from `id` is equal

Comment: It's not purely cosmetic, it's not necessary to start streaming at that point yet ... applying the WHERE will limit what has to send over the line.